# Parsing binary data in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary

We're doing a major rewrite of a project previously written in C into Ruby. We have a bunch of C structures, written as C typedefs:

```
struct my_struct {
    uint32_t foo;
    uint8_t bar;
    char baz[80];
}
```

Is there a quick way to load them all up in Ruby? For example, is there some way to convert these definitions into something that resembles code like

```
@foo = io.read(4).unpack('V')[0]
@bar = io.read(1).unpack('C')[0]
@baz = io.read(80)
```

There are literally tons of it, I'd rather not convert them by hand...

Comment: Can you describe where this data is stored and what format it will be in? It sounds like it might be stored as binary in a file but without more information on delimiters and file structure its hard to give a full answer.

Comment: @TylerFerraro The data is either sent across the network (and thus resides in memory when it's time to parse it) or read/written in local disc files.

Comment: @theTinMan I've described what I've done so far — I'm convert these parsers by hand, i.e. rewriting C data structures in a way I've shown above. Of course, I've searched Google, etc, done all the basic scouting, but found no answer. Please advice how can I improve the question?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but I wanted to mention that the code you've given could be more simply expressed as `@foo, @bar, @baz = io.read(85).unpack('VCA*')`.

Comment: This is not very *quick* but I would first use [cast](https://github.com/oggy/cast), then iterate over the nodes to *print* the [BinData](https://github.com/dmendel/bindata/) lines...

Answer (score 2):

Use [BinData](https://github.com/dmendel/bindata/).

```
class MyStruct < BinData::Record
    endian :little
    uint32 :foo
    uint8  :bar
    string :baz, read_length: 80
end
```

It's pretty much a 1:1 mapping between C structs and BinData Records. It should be easy to write a conversion script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tons of them, you may want to write a quick program to parse the C code for you :)

Then the parsing code could create the corresponding ruby code from the C code.

Comment: I'm not very good at programming parsers, it's always been a major space in my CS knowledge, so I'd rather not. If I must, could you recommend some good books on writing parsers then?

Comment: I wouldn't go all the way in writing a C level parser, just write enough to recognize a struct { } and convert it.  The goal here is to write throw-away code that will convert something for us once.  So, it doens't matter how terrible it is... to some point :)